# Iterating through table columns until null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working with some data on SQL Server through Access 2010 that I have no flexibility to change, only query on. Each individual entity gets one ID, and may have a list of attributes that follow it with no particular max or min entries. The solution that the person who created this dataset had was to create 37 different column sets of attributes. For each attribute, there are 4 columns (though only 2 are useful). In effect, there are 148 columns to represent possibly having 37 items, though most columns past group 3 or 4 are NULL. There is some consistency though- values go to the first column groups first. As soon as any column has a null value, it can be assumed that every column after it is also null. If the first column is null, it has no attributes. Data looks somewhat like this:

`| ID | Attr1 | Code1 | Attr2  | Code2  | Attr3  | Code3  |
|----|-------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1  | Foo   | 2     | Bar    | 1      | (null) | (null) |
| 2  | Bar   | 2     | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 3  | Bar   | 1     | Foo    | 1      | Bar    | 2      |`

What would be the best way to query on this so that if someone wants CodeX=1(X being any number), the query returns results even if that row has Code1=1 or Code37=1. I considered doing something like this:

```
A.Mod1=1
Or A.Mod2=1
Or A.Mod3=1
Or A.Mod4=1
...
```

But that looks hideous and is about as DRY as a flash flood. It becomes especially horrendous if I want to target both attributes and codes, which I likely will do. I looked over CASE briefly in hopes that I could think of a way to use that to iterate through and bring me back the value of the first null value, but my drafts don't make a lot of sense and are just as messy/heavily nested.

Any thoughts on how to get through these aside from the really ugly method suggested above?

Comment: can you do passthrough queries? use the COALESCE keyword with columns in reverse order to get the first non-null value in a list of columns

Comment: I can do pass-through, yes. Let me take a quick look at that then.

Comment: Okay, so that is getting closer to what I need. One of the steps I want to do following this is to be able to return all values that aren't null, so that could save some typing.

I also want to be able to match on specific values, which means I'd need to write out the expression each time for coalesce because "NOT NULL" isn't quite meaningful enough. Then I'm right back where I started with my OR statements.

Comment: If you can create a view in SQL Server, create one to normalize the data structure, and then query against that view.  You could also create that view as an Access query, but the performance would probably be a lot poorer.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't add views to the server. We have read only for server side tables, but we can make local tables. Would I be able to transpose columns as rows with a view, map each attribute to it's own row?

Comment: If it were me in this case, I'd have some data structures that hold column names, then have a generic routine to find the index of the last populated column, then you can write a routing to generically build the search conditions based on the columns that have data and the value you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways to unpivot your data. Doing this, allows you to just add a where clause for your parameter. I.e. just add `where code = 1` to the first query or `where codes = 1` to the second. You could also pivot this back up if necessary, but this normalizes it a ton. As you said, you could do this with a crazy long CASE statement, but it's dry and lengthy.

```
declare @table table(ID int, Attr1 varchar(16), Code1 varchar(16),Attr2 varchar(16), Code2 varchar(16), Attr3 varchar(16), Code3 varchar(16))
insert into @table
values
(1,'Foo',2,'Bar',1,NULL,NULL),
(2,'Bar',2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(3,'Bar',1,'Foo',1,'Bar',2)

select
    t.ID, 
    c.Attribute,
    c.Code
from @table t
cross apply (
            select Attr1, Code1 union all
            select Attr2, Code2 union all
            select Attr3, Code3 
            ) c (Attribute, Code)
where
    Attribute is not null


select
    ID,
    Attributes,
    Codes
from(
     select ID, Attr1, Code1, Attr2, Code2, Attr3, Code3 
     from @table) main
unpivot
(Attributes for Attribute in (Attr1, Attr2, Attr3)) attr
unpivot
(Codes for Code in (Code1, Code2, Code3)) cod
where
    right(Attribute,1) = right(Code,1)
```

Performance wise, it will likely be faster to **NOT** unpivot the data, but let the optimizer use the logic below with simple boolean comparisions

```
declare @Code int = 2
declare @Attr varchar(64) = null

select
    t.*
from @table t
where
    (Code1 = @Code or
     Code2 = @Code or
     Code3 = @Code or
     @Code is null)
     and
     (Attr1 = @Attr or
      Attr2 = @Attr or
      Attr3 = @Attr or
      @Attr is null)
```

Comment: I understand roughly where you are going with this, and it is quite helpful. As far as execution goes, would this perform better than 37 conditions combined by OR statements? I fear that performing a complex operation like this on an already large database would cut heavily into my performance. My code will be running mostly in the background and user input will define what code and/or attribute is being searched, so end user performance is top priority. Unfortunately, downloading a local modified copy of the table would also defeat the purpose, as this table is updated near monthly.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to tell which would perform better.. that would depend on your structure, indexes, etc. The only way to really tell is test it both ways, on a test system or during off hours or whatever. If you run it and it take longer than a few seconds (or what ever your threshold is) just kill the query and try the other way. To be honest, a large boolean statement would likely be the fastest, though your query will be long it will likely perform well. I'll update with that on the bottom.

Comment: @AndrewMcPheron updated the answer. The optimizer will almost certainly find the last query the fastest. You can set either, both, or neither of the parameters to null.

Comment: I don't recall changing my answer much since asking it, but alright.